# Is p2==NULL and !*p2 same?

Tags: c, pointers, null

Below is the code

```
char* StrStr(const char *str, const char *target) {
  if (!*target) return str;
  char *p1 = (char*)str;
  while (p1 != NULL) {
    char *p1Begin = p1, *p2 = (char*)target;
    while (*p1 && *p2 && *p1 == *p2) {
      p1++;
      p2++;
    }
    if (!*p2)
      return p1Begin;
    p1 = p1Begin + 1;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

If I use if(p2==NULL) instead of if(!*p2) then I get segmentation fault. Why?

Line 14 http://codepad.org/ZUqXVCJ9

Is if(!*p2) is same as if(p==NULL)?

Why I am getting segmentation fault.

Comment: You probably want to do `if (!p2)` and `if (!target)`

Comment: why you're casting a `const char *` into `char *`?

Comment: @Rishi no, he doesn't want, that is specifically testing for the null terminator on the strings; these pointers shouldn't ever become null pointers. also the test `while (p1 != NULL)` most probably should be `while (!*p1)`

Comment: Note that `while (*p1 && *p2 && (*p1 == *p2)) {` can be simplified to `while (*p1 && (*p1 == *p2)) {`.

Comment: from http://www.firmcodes.com/write-c-code-to-implement-the-strstr-function-to-search-for-a-substring/

can anybody help me out how the address of the string is returned (Line o 18)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No `p2 == NULL` is not the same as `!*p2`. If anything, `p2 == NULL` is equivalent to `!p2`.

When you do `!*p2` you first *dereference* the pointer `p2`, and then check if the value `p2` is *pointing* to is "false". If `p2` is a null pointer, that dereference will not be valid.

Answer (score 3):

It's not the same. When you do `*p2` it reads a `char` from the memory location `p2` is pointing to. If `p2` happens to be `NULL` this results in a segmentation fault, as `NULL` (or `0`) is no legal memory location to read from or write to. `p2 == NULL` checks if the pointer itself is `NULL`.